# Generate radio button list from enum

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor

I have an enum that I want to use to auto-populate a radio button list. I'm getting the correct values on the buttons, but the labels next to the buttons are just the same number as the corresponding value. I'm not sure what to put in the label instead of `@source` Here is my enum:

```cs
public enum SourceEnum
    {
       Youtube,
       Reddit,
       Instagram,
       Facebook,
       [Display(Name ="From Phone or Computer")]
       PhoneComputer,
       Other,
    }
```

And my foreach loop:

```cs
 @foreach (int source in (Timelineinfo.SourceEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Timelineinfo.SourceEnum)))
      {
        <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" asp-for="Timelineinfo.Source" class="form-check-input" value="@source">
           <label asp-for="Timelineinfo.Source" class="form-check-label">@source</label>
        </div>
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by changing from `int source` to `var source`, and then changing value to `@((int)source)` so my code now looks like:

```cs
 @foreach (var source in (Timelineinfo.SourceEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(Timelineinfo.SourceEnum)))
      {
        <div class="form-check">
           <input type="radio" asp-for="Timelineinfo.Source" class="form-check-input" value="@((int)source)">
           <label asp-for="Timelineinfo.Source" class="form-check-label">@source</label>
        </div>
      }
```